# Fetch data in the format [1,2,3] from mysql database using php and jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, arrays, ajax

I have my jquery code which connects to `getdata.php`. Here the `val` is dynamic value and the function is called every time an option is selected from dropdown.

```
    function getMoleculeData(val){
      var molval=val;
      var url = 'getmoldata.php';
     $.ajax({ 
      url: url,
      data: 'molval='+molval,
      method:'POST',
      success: function(moldata) {        
      alert(moldata);
        }
     });
    }
```

My `getdata.php` code goes here

```
    <?php  
      $molval = $_POST['molval']; //  consider $_POST['molval']=ABC 
      $dbhost = "localhost";
      $dbuser = "root";
      $dbpass = "";
      $dbname= "userdata";
      $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
      mysql_select_db($dbname) or die ();   
       $query = "SELECT cm_id, CORP_RANK, CORP_MKT_SHARE, COMBINED_MOLECULE FROM PRODUCT_UNIVERSE_D WHERE COMBINED_MOLECULE ="."'$molval'";

       $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
       $i = 1; 
         $array = array();
         while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result) { 
         $array[] = $row;
         echo $row['CORP_RANK']; // etc
         } 

       ?>
```

Here is my table `PRODUCT_UNIVERSE_D`

```
   cmid  |  CORP_RANK | CORP_MKT_SHARE |  COMBINED_MOLECULE  |    DATE
     1   |     10     |       30       |         ABC         |  01-04-2013
     2   |     5      |       50       |         ABC         |  03-06-2013
     3   |     8      |       40       |         ABC         |  23-09-2013
     4   |     3      |       10       |         XYZ         |  05-01-2014
```

when I select ABC in dropdown, the same value is given in where clause and I am able to fetch the result. FOr the above code written in `getdata.php` the output that I got is `1058` i.e the values of CORP_RANK where COMBINED_MOLECULE = 'ABC'. But the requirement is I have to get the result in the form of `[10,5,8]`. How do I get the result in this array format and also how to fetch all the columns separately like $row['CORP_MKT_SHARE'] = `[10,50,40]` and display them separately in success function of `index.php` as

```
    [10,5,8] and [10,50,40] for furthur use
```

Please help me out, as I am not perfect in fundamentals of arrays I am unable to get the result. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're aiming to output the data into json format.

```
example:
$array = array(1,2,3);
var_dump(json_encode($array));
```

You'll get this output:

```
string(7) "[1,2,3]"
```

It's better to change your loop as this:

```
for($array = array();$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);$array[] = $row);
json_encode($array);
```

This is what the best way when you want to retrieve data from php file using ajax.

using your code:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
   $rank[] = $row['CORP_RANK'];
   $share[] = $row['CORP_MKT_SHARE'];
}
$array = array('CORP_RANK'=>$rank,'CORP_MKT_SHARE'=>$share);
json_encode($array);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am getting the same output i.e.  something like [{"0":"1","cm_id":"1","1":"5","CORP_RANK":"5","2":"50","CORP_MKT_SHARE":"50","3":"ABC","COMBINED_MOLECULE":"ABC"},{"0":"2","cm_id":"2","1":"8","CORP_RANK":"8","2":"50","CORP_MKT_SHARE":"50","3":"ABC","COMBINED_MOLECULE":"XYZ"}]  but  I want to get it in the format [ABC, ABC, ABC] for example for COMBIND_MOLECULE and [10, 5. 8] for CORP_RANK @Ronnel Padernal

Comment: for($array = array();$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);$array[] = $row['CORP_RANK']);

to get only the CORP_RANK data,

Comment: Thanq.. it works :) I have one more doubt. How to get these value separately like if I want to append $row['CORP_RANK'] to a div and $row['CORP_MKT_SHARE'] to other div how do I append after fetching it from getdata.php to the jquery code

Comment: you can convert the json data from getdata,php to javascript using JSON.parse(json)

Comment: @ DarkZ3ro11 can you give the code please. I am very new to this field. please don't mind

Comment: check this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/912247/4660348 or this: http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/php-js/json/parse.php

Comment: I have tried the code                   $.ajax({ 
          url: 'getdata.php',
          data: 'molval='+molval,
    method:'POST',
   dataType:'json',
          success: function(moldata) { alert(moldata.CORP_RANK);   
   
          }
        });      // I am getting output as undefined